# addChild throws an exception

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am working on a game. I have designed a process bar in Flash and linked it to AS 3.
In the main class (main_c.as) I am assigning a var to the stage :

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;


public class main_c extends MovieClip {

    static public var stageRef:Stage;
    public var s:start_b;
    public var bar:timer_bar;
    public function main_c() 
    {
        // constructor code
        stageRef = stage;
        s = new start_b();
        addChild(s);
        s.x = 260;
        s.y = 225;

    }


}

}
```

then there is a start_b class which is to create a button and on click to fire the constructor of the third class (game.as). Here is the code of start_b :

```
package  {

import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class start_b extends SimpleButton {

    public var g:game;

    public function start_b() 
    {
        // constructor code
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start_g);
    }

    public function start_g(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        g = new game();
        this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start_g);
        this.visible = false;
    }
}
```

And in the last class I want to addChild the status bar with reference to the stage, but when I run I get error -

`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at game()
    at start_b/start_g()`

here is the code of the third class (game.as):

```
package{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import main_c;

public class game extends MovieClip {
    public var points:Number;
    public var ptw:Number;
    public var time:Timer;
    public var bar:timer_bar = new timer_bar();
    public var cnt:main_c;

    public function game()
    {
        //restartirane na igrata (nulirane)
        main_c.stageRef.addChild(bar);
        points = 0;
        time = new Timer(50);
        time.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, flow);
        time.start();
        trace("d");


    }

    public function flow(t:TimerEvent):void 
    {
        //code
        //bar.y++;
    }

    public function addPoints():void
    {
        //function code here
    }

    public function removePoints():void
    {
        //function code here
    }

    public function checkTime():void
    {
        //function code here
    }

    public function end():void
    {
        //function code here
    }

}

}
```

If you could help me I will be very glad :-) Thanks and nice day!

Comment: please if someone have solution write it :-)

Comment: It looks like you already have some good answers, but just a couple of notes about good coding practices:  1) Class names should be capitalized and use UpperCamelCase (the same way the standard Flash library classes are named, ex: MovieClip).  So, your `timer_bar` class should be named `TimerBar`, your `main_c` class should probably be named `MainC`, etc.  2) It's typically desirable to use names that are at least a little more human-readable than single characters.  Your line `s = new start_b();` would be a lot more readable as `startBtn = new StartButton();`. Anyway, just some pointers :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your stage is ready:

Main_c / constructor :

```
   public function main_c() 
   {
    if (stage)
    {
        init();
    }
    else
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }
   }
```

Main_c / init :

```
private function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

    stageRef = stage;
    s = new start_b();
    addChild(s);
    s.x = 260;
    s.y = 225;
}
```

Comment: Wellcome :) ..and always mark the answer accepted if it was right answer to your question.. and other good answers, you can give em vote. And btw Ian has some good tips in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Clue # 1:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at game() at start_b/start_g()

This means that some object in the `game` constructor is null, but you are trying to access a member function or property of that object.

Breaking it up:

```
main_c.stageRef.addChild(bar);
points = 0;
time = new Timer(50);
time.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, flow);
time.start();
trace("d");
```

The only possible cause of the error here is the first line

```
main_c.stageRef.addChild(bar);
```

so, the solution to this would be to see if `main_c.stageRef` is null, and act accordingly

My solution to this: Redefine the constructor of the game class:

```
public function game() {
    init();
}

public function init() {
    if(main_c.stageRef) {
        //restartirane na igrata (nulirane)
        main_c.stageRef.addChild(bar);
        points = 0;
        time = new Timer(50);
        time.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, flow);
        time.start();
        trace("d");
    } else {
        callLater(init);
    }
}
```

Documentation for the [callLater](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layoutperformance_12.html) method

On an unrelated note, ActionScript class names start with a UPPERCASE letter by convention. This helps differentiate them from instance names which start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll keep it in mind :-) You really help me, have a nice day!